# Facebook Pixel event on button

Tags: javascript, facebook, onclick, facebook-javascript-sdk

How do I track a specific button using the CompleteRegistration event in Facebook Pixel?

In the heading section I've added this code

```
    <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
    n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
    document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

    fbq('init', 'REMOVED');
    fbq('track', "PageView");
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=REMOVED&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Now I have a button in the following format. I have a couple buttons on my site, but this is the specific one I want to track for that event.

```
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $buttonUrl; ?>" name="thanks_page" />
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary-01 btn-lg" name="save" value="Submit" id="final_step" /> 
                </span>
```

Comment: Well add a click handler, and inside call `fbq` ...?

Comment: @CBroe I've read about this, but its ver confusing to me. Would you be able to piece it together? Thank you.